# Disproving the metric of two nonempty closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am a novice in Analysis. I'd like to unleash my mental gymnastic on this exercise but I am not certain about what I did, If I am wrong, could anyone explain to me why my solution is not valid? Then giving an acceptable solution(s) are welcomed.

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space.
Prove or disprove that $D(A, B) > 0$ for any nonempty disjoint closed $A,B \subset X.$

Where, $d(x, A) = \inf\limits_{a\in A} d(x, a)$ and $D(A, B) = \inf\limits_{a\in A, b \in B} d(a, b)$

Since $A$ is a closed set, it has a closed ball i.e., $x\in X, \ \epsilon >0,  \ \overline{B}_\epsilon(x): = \{y \in X \ |\ d(x,y) \le \epsilon\}$, the closed ball of $B$ is similarly defined $\overline{B}_\epsilon(z): = \{y \in X \ | \ d(z,y) \le \epsilon\}$. Observe that their discrete are $d(\cdot) \le \epsilon$. Then $D(A, B) \le \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$ which contradicts $D(A, B) >0.$  We've disproved.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that a point in a closed set has a closed ball around it that's contained within the set.  For example, consider the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @holala Consider $\Bbb R$ with the usual distance metric. Let $A=\{3,4,5,6,...\}$ and $B=\left\{3+\frac 13, 4+\frac 14,5+\frac 15,6+\frac 16,....\right\}$. Now, $$D(A,B)=\inf_{a\in A,b\in B}|a-b|\leq \inf_{n\in\Bbb N, n\geq 3}\bigg|n-\left(n+\frac 1 n\right)\bigg|=\inf_{n\in\Bbb N, n\geq 3}\frac 1 n=0.$$

Comment: @Mathlover. That's splendid counter example. You should've posted as an answer to earn votes. Any way, thanks! for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true in general. It is true if one of the sets is compact (then the infimal distance function to the other set is continuous on a compact set, and hence has a minimum), but it's not true if both are simply assumed to be closed.

Your proof is difficult for me to follow, but as best I can tell, it makes a couple of errors. First, closed, non-empty sets may not contain non-trivial balls. For example, singleton sets are closed, but when the point is not isolated, they will contain no ball of positive radius.

Secondly, and more seriously, you $\varepsilon > 0$ seems to depend on where you put the centre of your particular ball. You might get a large $\varepsilon > 0$ for one point $x \in A$, but a much smaller one for a different point $x' \in A$. You can't then fix a particular $\varepsilon > 0$ that applies for all the points $x \in A$, and therefore conclude that $d(A, B) \ge \varepsilon$.

As a specific counterexample, consider the metric space $\Bbb{R}^2$, and the sets
\begin{align*}
A &= \left\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x > 0 \text{ and } y \ge \frac{1}{x}\right\} \\
B &= \left\{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x < 0 \text{ and } y \ge -\frac{1}{x}\right\}.
\end{align*}
Note that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ simply because they contain points with $x$ coordinates of different signs. Further, $(1/n, n) \in A$ while $(-1/n, n) \in B$, and
$$d\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}, n\right), \left(-\frac{1}{n}, n\right)\right) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + (n - n)^2} = \frac{2}{n} \to 0,$$
as $n \to \infty$. This implies the infimal distance is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

For an intuitive counterexample that disproves the statement, let $A$ be the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ and let $B$ be the graph of $y= \frac 1x$.  Both sets are closed and they asymptotically approach each other, but they are disjoint.